# jquery apply script to all divs based on index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some divs that get created dynamically. they look like this:

```
<div class="item-logo"><img src="XXX"></div>
<div class="item-move">Move Me</div> 

<div class="item-logo"><img src="XXX"></div>
<div class="item-move">Move Me</div> 

<div class="item-logo"><img src="XXX"></div>
<div class="item-move">Move Me</div>
```

Here is what I am trying to do so I can have one script that will add a class so each div is unique and then execute for each div.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

      $( ".item-logo" ).addClass(function( index ) {
      return "number-" + index;
    });
      $( ".item-move" ).addClass(function( index ) {
      return "blurb-" + index;
    });


      $(".number-" +index).mouseover(function() {
        // Set the effect type
        var effect = "slide";

        // Set the options for the effect type chosen
        var options = { direction: "left" };

        // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
        var duration = 500;

        $(".blurb-"+ index).toggle(effect, options, duration);

      }).mouseout(function(){
         $(".blurb-"+ index).hide('slide',{direction:'left'});

    });

    });

    </script>
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mess with adding classes, instead traverse the DOM. Apply the event handlers to all `.item-logo` instances. In the event handler, `this` will be the clicked element. `$(this).next()` will get the next div - which according to the markup is the `<div>` that you want to show and hide.

```
 $(".item-logo").mouseover(function() {
    // Set the effect type
    var effect = "slide";

    // Set the options for the effect type chosen
    var options = { direction: "left" };

    // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
    var duration = 500;

    $(this).next().toggle(effect, options, duration);

  }).mouseout(function(){
     $(this).next().hide('slide',{direction:'left'});
});
```

Comment: next() works in my simplified example. What if the divs looked like this:  [http://jsfiddle.net/daveferrara1/4gBGq/]     -- This seems to do some fishy things as you hover from image to image as well.

Comment: That's another question. Please post it as a new question and include a code example in the question itself (just as you did in your original post).

Comment: Here is the other question: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23461390/jquery-apply-script-to-all-divs-on-page)