# jquery apply script to all divs on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some divs that get created dynamically. they look like this:

```
<div class="item-logo"><img src="http://www.glitters20.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Funny-Face-9.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="item-move">No Move</div> 
    <div class="item-movee">No Move</div>
    <div class="item-moveee">No Move</div> 
    <div class="item-moveeee">Move Me</div> 

        <div class="item-logo"><img src="http://www.glitters20.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Funny-Face-9.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="item-move">No Move</div> 
    <div class="item-movee">No Move</div>
    <div class="item-moveee">No Move</div> 
    <div class="item-moveeee">Move Me</div>
```

Here is what I am trying to do so I can have one script that will execute for each div. Here is my script that is not working: I want to move  .item-moveeee

```
$(".item-logo").mouseover(function() {
    // Set the effect type
    var effect = "slide";

    // Set the options for the effect type chosen
    var options = { direction: "left" };

    // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
    var duration = 500;

    $(this).next().toggle(effect, options, duration);

  }).mouseout(function(){
     $(this).next().hide('slide',{direction:'left'});
});
```

Here is a fiddle that is not working: http://jsfiddle.net/daveferrara1/4gBGq/

Any help would be appreciated:

Comment: Please describe what you want/expect to happen based on the code above, and what is actually happening

Comment: But `$(this).next()` gets you `item-move` and not `item-moveeee`, according to the hierarchy you show here.

Comment: if you need to move only the .item-moveeee , replace $(this).next() with $(this).parent().find('.item-moveeee') and wrap all (.item-logo, .item-move, .item-movee, .item-moveee, .item-moveeee) in one container

Comment: @keypaul - that would not work, because it is not a descendant of `item-logo`, it is a sibling. The false indentation is misleading.

Comment: @j08691 -No I don't think that fiddle is going to do it. That always moves on the :first div regrdless of the hover.  I need them to be independent.

Comment: @PhistucK you are right, i've don't see all not was in a wrapper (i mean , item logo, etc.. i've edit my previous comment. Sorry

Comment: Hmmm, then like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/45MDG/? Will the structure always be the same?

Comment: Ok both keypaul and j08691 are viable solutions. The next()next() is a problem as its not future proof. I'll give the wrapper and then find.

Comment: Here the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/keypaul/U2w37/ IMO is best do hover on img (http://jsfiddle.net/keypaul/3asA3/) but i don't know what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @keypaul Here the fiddle [jsfiddle.net/keypaul/U2w37](http://jsfiddle.net/keypaul/U2w37)

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="item-logo"><img src="http://www.glitters20.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Funny-Face-9.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="item-move0">No Move</div> 
    <div class="item-move1">No Move</div>
    <div class="item-move2">No Move</div> 
    <div class="item-move3">Move Me</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="item-logo"><img src="http://www.glitters20.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Funny-Face-9.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="item-move0">No Move</div> 
    <div class="item-move1">No Move</div>
    <div class="item-move2">No Move</div> 
    <div class="item-move3">Move Me</div>
</div>


$(".item-logo").mouseover(function() {
    // Set the effect type
    var effect = "slide";

    // Set the options for the effect type chosen
    var options = { direction: "left" };

    // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
    var duration = 500;
    $(this).parent().find('.item-move3').toggle(effect, options, duration);

  }).mouseout(function(){
      $(this).parent().find('.item-move3').hide('slide',{direction:'left'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the point is as you stated that you're creating the `<div>`s dynamically. To make the jQuery function trigger for dynamically created objects try it like this:

#1 Give your `div`s a wrapper / parent:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="item-logo"><img src="http://www.glitters20.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Funny-Face-9.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="item-move">No Move</div> 
    <div class="item-movee">No Move</div>
    <div class="item-moveee">No Move</div> 
    <div class="item-moveeee">Move Me</div> 
</div>
```

#2 Try the following jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".parent").on("mouseover","div.item-logo",function () {
        // do what ever you want
        $(this).parent().find('.item-moveeee').html("*move*");
    });

    $(".parent").on("mouseout","div.item-logo",function () {
        // do what ever you want
        $(this).parent().find('.item-moveeee').html("Move Me");
    });
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TyQ4V/